# "Unsupported Python Version: 3.5" in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, ptvs

First I thought this is a version problem, so I downgraded the version from python 3.5 to 2.7 but still it didn't work. The same error **"Unsupported python version 3.5"**.
Please help.
Note: I've installed the plugin for python in visual studio stated as "PTVS 2.1 VS 2013" (which is the latest according to visual studio's website.)

Comment: Is this visual studio 2013 professional or express?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/132440)?

Comment: yes i already installed it but getting the same error mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Debug | Options and Settings | Python Tools | Environment Options, you can set it to use Python 2.7 (that is, it is not necessary to uninstall Python 3.5). PTVS seems to default to the latest installed version of Python even if it is not compatible with it.

[image]